# Image height issue on iOS Chrome/Safari (iFrame?)

Tags: css, webflow

Site:
https://thomasgristdesign.webflow.io

If you click/tap on 'Rio ESG' on Chrome/Safari iOS the iFrame will load and inside of that the images don't display, yet they do on Chrome/Safari OSX.

The images have the `projectimage` class and the following properties.

`.projectimage { width: 100%; max-width:100%:}`

The image is a flex child.

I thought it might be some sort of cross-domain iframe thing but specifying a height for the image e.g. 100px means that the image appears in the iFrame on mobile. But I don't want to do this as it has a responsive width and I want to maintain the aspect ratio.

If I visit one of the iframes directly on mobile e.g. https://thomasgristdesign.webflow.io/rio then the images load.

Adding `height:auto` to `.projectimage` didn't work...

Any ideas?

Images in iFrame without height:
[image]

Images in iFrame with specified 100px height:
[image]